# tableView: multiple sections with different style

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header, sections

I am trying to create a single table in Xcode and I want 3 sections in that table each with different headers.

I want to stick only the header of last section when it scrolls on top not the other sections.

Is there a way to do so please suggest me..

Answer (score 3):

1- Yes, you can do that. In `numberOfSections` method of UITableViewDelegate, specify how many sections you want. And in `viewForHeaderInSection` method of UITableviewDelegate, provide a custom view for each section.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    // Make custom header view for each section
    if section == 0 {
        let header1 = UIView()
        return header1

    } else if section == 1 {
        let header2 = UIView()
        return header2

    } else if section == 2 {
        let header3 = UIView()
        return header3
    }
}
```

2- No, you can not do that. UITableView does not allow you to specify that which particular header should stick to the top and which one should not.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UITableView style to **Plain**. It will stick all the section header while scrolling.

**I think that is not possible to stick the particular section header.**

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same behaviour by having a custom cell that would act as the header in the first two sections. And then remove the actual header for those.

For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 1) && indexPath.row == 0 {
        return HeaderCell()
    }

    // return your desired cells (make sure to handle the number of
    // rows properly as there is effectively 1 more than normal in
    // in the first two sections now)
}
```

You'll also need to adjust the headers for the first two sections:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 2 { return YourHeaderView() }

    return nil
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 2 { return yourHeight }

    return 0
}
```

Also, in the `numberOfRows` delegate function, you should make sure you add 1 (which will be the `HeaderCell`).